# First i create Home.js in my component then i try to render markdown in my home component

Tags: reactjs, markdown, jsx

In my Home.js component the code following :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import HomepageMarkdown from '../../markdown/homepage.md';
import Image from '../../markdown/image.md';
import './homepage.css'

class Homepage extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = { 
            markdown : '', 
            markdwonimage : ''
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        fetch(HomepageMarkdown).then(res => res.text()).then(text => this.setState({ markdown: text }));
        fetch(Image).then(res => res.text()).then(text => this.setState({ markdwonimage: text }));
    }

    render(){
        const { markdown, markdwonimage } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <ReactMarkdown source={markdwonimage} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6 content-section">
                        <ReactMarkdown source={markdown} />
                        <div className="publish">
                            <div className="publish-date">
                                <p>16 Juni 2019</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="publish-detail">
                                <p>Selengkapnya ></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>         
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Homepage
```

How do i load more .md file in ReactJS Component ? For example when i add .md file in my markdown folder automatically in my Home.js file render more markdown file

Answer (score 0):

React runs on client side, meaning it doesn't have possibility to know about the files in your components' folders. What you should be looking into is creating NodeJS service which would use file system to scan your directory for all md files and then return their content as a result of GET request you would be making from your React app. Then you handle the response data on your end in your app. Some reading: [on creating simple rest API using NodeJS and Express](https://medium.com/@onejohi/building-a-simple-rest-api-with-nodejs-and-express-da6273ed7ca9) and [NodeJS file system](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)